# How to insert "event dummy" (?) based on time interval in different dataframe

Tags: r, events, panel, time-series, dummy-data

I have a dataframe which provides the start and end date of an event for different countries. Events can occur for several times for each country (e.g. country A).

```
Start.Year <- c("1990","1992","1997","1995")
End.Year <- c("1995","1993","2000","1996")
Country <- c("A","B","A","C")
a <- data.frame(Start.Year,End.Year,Country)
a$Start.Year <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Start.Year))
a$End.Year <- as.numeric(as.character(a$End.Year))

      Start.Year End.Year Country
       1990     1995       A
       1992     1993       B
       1997     2000       A
       1995     1996       C
```

I have a second data frame which is in a time-series cross section format (Year/Country/Event(Yes/No).

```
b1 <-as.data.frame(expand.grid(year=(1990:2000), Country=unique(a$Country)))
b1$Event <-0   
b1$year <- as.numeric(as.character(b1$year))
```

How can I obtain the result below (apologies for the clumsy presentation). Event should be "1" when the year is between the start and end year of the first dataframe; for each country; the second dataframe exists already, meaning that I don't want to convert the first dataframe, but rather match (?) the information from the first dataframe to the second one.

I tried

```
b1$Event[a$Start.Year<=b1$year & a$End.Year>=b1$year] <- 1
```

but get "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" as error message. Grateful for any hint/advice!

Result aimed at:

```
  Year Country Event
  1990       A     1
  1991       A     1
  1992       A     1
  1993       A     1
  1994       A     1
  1995       A     1
  1996       A     0
  1997       A     1
  1998       A     1
  1999       A     1
  2000       A     1
  1990       B     0
  1991       B     0
  1992       B     1
  1993       B     1
  1994       B     0
  1995       B     0
  1996       B     0
  1997       B     0
  1998       B     0
  1999       B     0
  2000       B     0
  1990       C     0
  1991       C     0
  1992       C     0
  1993       C     0
  1994       C     0
  1995       C     1
  1996       C     1
  1997       C     0
  1998       C     0
  1999       C     0
  2000       C     0
```

Comment: There is a problem with your example. You're converting factors (years) into numeric values. You need to put a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` inside your `data.frame()` call or do `as.numeric(as.character(a$Start.Year))`, etc.

Comment: Or start the year variables as numeric/integer to begin with. I made that edit but it was reversed for some reason.

Comment: many thanks, wasn't aware of this. @ilir, I pushed 'skip' since I didn't have time to look more closely at your comments; apologies if 'skipping' deleted your comments. 

but as far as i can see these edits aren't solving my problem? Get the same error message. thx

Comment: @zoowalk no problem. I fixed it using my suggested method in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the rolling join feature in `data.table`. I have slightly changed (fixed?) your definition of `a` and removed the `Event` column in `b1`.

```
require(data.table)

Start.Year <- c(1990, 1992, 1997, 1995)
End.Year <- c(1995, 1993, 2000, 1996)
Country <- c("A", "B", "A", "C")
a <- data.frame(Start.Year, End.Year, Country)
a <- data.table(a)   ## convert to use feature

b1 <-as.data.frame(expand.grid(year=(1990:2000), Country=unique(a$Country)))
b1 <- data.table(b1)  ## convert 

##  join by Start.Year, setting matching keys for each dataset
setkey(a, Country, Start.Year)
setkey(b1, Country, year)

# the tricky part
# roll=TRUE means all years will match to 
# next smallest event Start.Year
ab <- a[b1, roll=TRUE] 

setnames(ab, c('Country', 'Year', 'Event'))  ## fix names
ab[Year > Event, Event:=NA]  ## stop index at end year
ab[!is.na(Event), Event:=1]  ## transform year markers to 1
ab[is.na(Event), Event:=0]   ## transform missing matches to 0
```

`ab` is the data in the format you want. You can use it just like a `data.frame` or convert it back if you don't want to keep it in that class. The join should be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of all the years by

```
yrs <- mapply(seq, a[[1]], a[[2]])
```

and a list of corresponding countries by

```
ctr <- rep(a[[3]], times=sapply(yrs, length) )
```

and then set the values within b1 by

```
b1$Event[match(sprintf("%s-%s", unlist(yrs), ctr), sprintf("%s-%s", b1$year, b1$Country))] <- 1
```

It's creating a composite year:country index, and for every b1 that matches an *a* event, setting it to 1.  If there are multiple events per country in a given year, they will get set to 1. (Also you've got different capitalisations of 'year' so watch out for that).